# how to manipulate arguments of a function

Tags: python, function

In this block of code, how can I alter the arguments of product()? like how can I make another function that when I give it a number like 4, it puts 4 x in product parentheses. I mean calculate `product(x,x,x,x)` instead of `product(x,x)`?

```
x=['A','C','G','T']
from itertools import product
def NumberToPattern(index,k):
    list1=list(product(x,x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`*` to unpack an iterable as arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), and multiplication, `*`, to multiply a tuple by a number to repeat it.

```
n = 4
x = "ACGT"
product(*(x,) * n)
```

will effectively result in

```
product(x, x, x, x)
```

Comment: I'm not sure suggesting a hackish alternative to `product(x, repeat=n)` is the best idea.

Comment: I'd forgotten product has that argument, good catch. This approach works for the general case and the question asked, though :)